# How can i make a batch file test if a file can be renamed?

Tags: batch-file

I need someone to help me make a bacth file that can test if a file can be renamed and then open a info box telling if the file can be renamed or not..

The problem in all of this is that I use interactive pdf files, and if two people on my network open the file at the same time, none of them can save the changes that they make in the file. But I know that if someone has the file open it can't be renamed, so that is why I need a batch file that can test if a file can be renamed without renaming it. If it can be renamed I need it to open a popup box saying "The file is ready for editing" and if it can't be renamed I need the popup box to say "The file is in use, please try again later"

I'll be very happy if ther is someone who is will to take on this challange :)

Best Regards
Dion

@echo off
ren "file.pdf" "file.pdf" 2>nul || (
  echo Sorry, the file is in use.
  echo Please try again later.
else start "C:\Test" file.pdf
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost answered your own question, without realizing it :-)

Simply attempt to rename a file to the same name. If it succeeds, then the file is not locked and there is no harm. If it fails, then you know the file is locked.

For example:

```
@echo off
ren "yourFile.pdf" "yourFile.pdf" 2>nul || (
  echo Sorry, file is locked by another user
  rem Take some error action, perhaps GOTO or EXIT /B
)
rem Now open the pdf file
```

But beware - this strategy is not foolproof because you have a race condition. If two processes run against the same file at nearly the same time, then they both may "rename" the file successfully before either has a chance to open the file.

Comment: Thanks @dbenham  the code is almost perfect :)  
I just need to add a start command so if the file is not in use it will start the pdf file.. here is my take on it, (see original post top)

Comment: @DionChristensen - That looks good, though the `"C:\Test"` throws me a bit - not sure what your intent is with that. The START command will interpret the first argument as a window title if the first argument is quoted like that, though the executeable program may very well override that window title with its own. Even if it has no effect, providing a title may be critical if the program argument requires quotes due to something like spaces in the path. If you intend `"C:\Test"` to be the path where your pdf is located, then the proper syntax would be `start "" "c:\test\file.pdf"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
ren "pdffile.pdf" "renameto.pdf"
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo The file cannot be renamed.
    rem The following line makes a dialog box saying that an error happened:
    echo msgbox "The file could not be renamed.">"%TEMP%\msg.vbs" && cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\msg.vbs" && del "%TEMP%\msg.vbs"
    rem put other commands here
)
```